# video editing by frames in the terminal

Tags: video, editing, transcoding

Recently I setup mythtv.  It works quite well however it records shows in a very large format and with commercials.  It does document where the commercials start and end frames.  With that said is there any video editing program out that that will allow me to put in a list of start and end frames via the terminal that will just cut out those sections while transcoding and not change anything else?

I have looked at several different applications and it seems that most of them allow you to take off the end or beginning.  I haven't seen anything that allows me to select sections and cut them out.

I would have mythtv do this on it's own however I store the videos on a san and want a different server to take over that load since it itself is underpowered.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that come to mind is install MythBackend on "different server" and use its built-in features. Avidemux has a command-line mode, but it seems like a serious undertaking to script something like that. I would approach it something like this, but only as a last resort:

- Generate your list of start and end frames of all the keeps or cuts.
- Iterate through that list and build an Avidemux cmdline.
- Start avidemux and open your file.  Set the Begin, End frames of the
  first chunk you want to **keep.**
- Export that chunk to a tempfile
- Repeat until you process all the begin/end pairs. Keep appending the
  parts of the video you want to keep onto the temp file.
- Rename the temp file

Your Mythtv cutlist might only contain the begin/end frames of the commercials, so you'd have to compute the begin/end frames of the parts to keep. This link on extracting closed captions might help you extract the cutlist http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Closed_captioning